# How can I output raw text properly formatted for reading and filing in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I need the output of the command below, ie `"* master\n  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master\n  remotes/origin/master\n"` to be output for reading.

```
iex(26)> System.cmd "git", ["-C", "/home/vonhabsi/workpad/Cuis/.git","branch","-a"]  
{"* master\n  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master\n  remotes/origin/master\n",     
 0}
```

ie in the form

```
* master                              
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

This `System.cmd` docs adds `into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)` to the command

```
iex(27)> System.cmd "git", ["-C", "/home/vonhabsi/workpad/Cuis/.git","branch","-a"], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
{%IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}, 0}
iex(28)>
```

What function do I need to take the `"* master\n  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master\n  remotes/origin/master\n"` from the tuple and output it as:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

The additional output  `{%IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}, 0}` is unwanted.
In short how do you take a piece of raw text with `\n` newlines and output it as it should be printed.

How do you also save it to a file?

Comment: You mean like `{s, _} = System.cmd(...)` and `IO.puts(s)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to extract elements from a tuple:

- pattern matching as @Dogbert suggests
- elem/2

As for writing to a file, in iex> try `h File.` and tab to get a list of functions. Then `h File.write <cr>` to get help.

One possible solution

```
line = System.cmd(...) |> elem(0)
File.write("path_to_file", line)
```

If your writing a lot of lines, you may want to open the file first. Look at the help for it with iex> `h File.open`